# Emit YAML iterating through boost property tree (recursively)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree, yaml-cpp

I have a small but complex tree structure. Using, boost property tree as a container i am trying to iterate through the tree and subsequently emit it to the yaml file using [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/wiki/How-To-Emit-YAML) library.

For instance, i have a small nested property tree:

```
fibonacci:
  type: series
  entities:
    golden_ratio:
      ratio: 2.3
    function:
      power_series: 2
```

I want my yaml file to look exactly like this.

I wrote a recursive function to iterate through the tree and emit to yaml.

```
//Member variable
YAML::Emitter m_out

void iterator(const boost::property_tree::ptree& tree, const std::string& key)
{
    for (const auto& item: tree)
    {
        if (item.second.data().empty()) //check if map node
        {
            m_out << YAML::BeginMap;
            m_out << YAML::Key << item.first;
        }
        else if (!item.second.data().empty()) //else it is key/value pair
        {
            m_out << YAML::Key << item.first;
            m_out << YAML::Value << item.second.data();
        }
        if (!item.second.empty()) //If the node has child
        {
            iterator(item.second, item.first);
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling the function with a emtpy key as `iterator(root, "")`. I know that the property tree works as key/value pairs, whereas, Yaml-cpp has node designations. In the code i am just trying to assume type of tree node based on value (no value - Map node, else - key/value node)

Apparently, my emitted yaml file doesn't possess the desired tree structure as presented above since my logic is wrong. I would like to make a recursive function which can iterate through any kind of tree and emit it to yaml file.
Is it possible to iterate tree and subsequently emit to yaml recursively? If yes, i would appreciate some ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I took your desired YAML and put it through an [online converter](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-xml-csv/cb968d75) to get a "reliable" ptree representation (which you interestingly left out of the question).

Then I proceeded to do a simple ptree roundtrip for sanity checks:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6291e97219a44cc9)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::property_tree::ptree;

std::istringstream sample_json();
ptree sample_ptree();

int main() {
    write_json(std::cout, sample_ptree());
}

std::istringstream sample_json() {
    return std::istringstream(R"({
        "fibonacci": {
            "type": "series",
            "entities": {
                "golden_ratio": {
                    "ratio": 2.3
                },
                "function": {
                    "power_series": 2
                }
            }
        }
    })");
}

ptree sample_ptree() {
    ptree pt;
    {
        auto stream = sample_json();
        read_json(stream, pt);
    }
    return pt;
}
```

Prints

```
{
    "fibonacci": {
        "type": "series",
        "entities": {
            "golden_ratio": {
                "ratio": "2.3"
            },
            "function": {
                "power_series": "2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### `to_yaml` take #1

The simplest is, of course, to read the same JSON, and let `yaml-cpp` do the conversion:

```
auto stream = sample_json();
std::cout << YAML::Load(stream) << "\n";
```

Prints:

```
{fibonacci: {type: series, entities: {golden_ratio: {ratio: 2.3}, function: {power_series: 2}}}}
```

### `to_yaml` take #2: pretty print

First off

- naming is important. `iterator` doesn't describe the function, and clashes with the [well-known concept from the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator)
- the `key` argument is unused
- you only ever `BeginMap`, how are you expecting a valid tree if you don't have `EndMap` anywhere in the code?
- No global variables please. They make your code brittle (non-deterministic, non-idempotent, non-reentrant, not threadsafe etc.). Just pass that `Emitter&` as a parameter.

I'd make it MUCH simpler:

```
void to_yaml(ptree const& node, YAML::Emitter &m_out) {
    if (node.empty()) {
        m_out << YAML::Value << node.data(); 
    } else {
        m_out << YAML::BeginMap;
        for (auto const&item : node) {
            m_out << YAML::Key << item.first;
            to_yaml(item.second, m_out);
        }
        m_out << YAML::EndMap;
    }
}
```

Now, to have a convenient entry point, add an overload:

```
std::string to_yaml(ptree const& tree) {
    YAML::Emitter out;
    to_yaml(tree, out);
    return out.c_str();
}
```

Now you can print the result by doing:

```
std::cout << to_yaml(sample_ptree()) << "\n";
```

Prints:

```
fibonacci:
  type: series
  entities:
    golden_ratio:
      ratio: 2.3
    function:
      power_series: 2
```

### Full Listing

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
using boost::property_tree::ptree;

std::istringstream sample_json();
ptree sample_ptree();

#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"

void to_yaml(ptree const& node, YAML::Emitter &m_out) {
    if (node.empty()) {
        m_out << YAML::Value << node.data(); 
    } else {
        m_out << YAML::BeginMap;
        for (auto const&item : node) {
            m_out << YAML::Key << item.first;
            to_yaml(item.second, m_out);
        }
        m_out << YAML::EndMap;
    }
}

std::string to_yaml(ptree const& tree) {
    YAML::Emitter out;
    to_yaml(tree, out);
    return out.c_str();
}

int main() {
    write_json(std::cout, sample_ptree());

    {
        auto stream = sample_json();
        std::cout << YAML::Load(stream) << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << to_yaml(sample_ptree()) << "\n";
}

std::istringstream sample_json() {
    return std::istringstream(R"({
        "fibonacci": {
            "type": "series",
            "entities": {
                "golden_ratio": {
                    "ratio": 2.3
                },
                "function": {
                    "power_series": 2
                }
            }
        }
    })");
}

ptree sample_ptree() {
    ptree pt;
    {
        auto stream = sample_json();
        read_json(stream, pt);
    }
    return pt;
}
```

Comment: thank you for very well written answer! It cleared up so many confusions i had. I hope it will help lot of others.